# Add trailing commas to ensure .csv rows have same number of columns

Tags: bash, macos, csv, unix, awk

I have a comma delimited file with rows that have an uneven number of columns.

I would like to add trailing commas (with empty values) so that each column has the maximum number of columns.

I currently have:

```
i1, 12, 15
i2, 00, 01
i3
i4, 18, 21, 36
```

*This is just an example and the actual files vary in maximum number of columns.*

My desired output for the above example is:

```
i1, 12, 15,  
i2, 00, 01,  
i3,   ,   ,  
i4, 18, 21, 36
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: FWIW... Your desired output for `i3,   ,   ,` is not the standard for a CSV file! `i3,,,` would be the proper format, otherwise the value of the cells after `i3` is 3 spaces instead of what would normally be an empty cell. Why do you want the unpopulated cells to have three spaces instead of the normal empty value that placing the commas directly after each other would produce when i.e. exporting to CSV in Numbers would produce?

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks for bringing this up.  The output could be `i3,,,`. I put the spaces in my 'desired output' above just to clarify I want the same number of columns (i.e. commas) in each row. Although the spaces do not really impact my downstream use of the CSV - I did edit the answer from @james-brown to remove the spaces for my own use.

Comment: Adding spaces does not clarify what you wan't, rather it introduces erroneous data! AFAIC Both your input and output is malformed and contains erroneous data as the only character between the actual data should be the delimiter, in this case a comma.

Comment: @user3439894 Agreed. To reveal more, my actual data was just tab delimited, and not comma + space delimited. In the future though, I will keep in mind that CSVs should only have data separated by the delimiter (e.g. comma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One for GNU awk. It processes the file twice. On the first run it determines the maximum field count, on the second it adds the "empty" (well, two spaces) fields to the end:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=", "            # field separators
}
NR==FNR {                  # first run
    if(maxnf<NF)           # find the biggest NF
        maxnf=NF
    next
}
NF<maxnf {
    nf=NF+1                # store NF+1 for for
    NF=maxnf               # reset the NF
    for(nf;nf<=NF;nf++)    # process the new fields
        $nf="  "
}1' file file              # output records
```

Output:

```
i1, 12, 15,   
i2, 00, 01,   
i3,   ,   ,   
i4, 18, 21, 36
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use awk to do the job:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "}NF<=3{for(i=NF+1;i<=4;i++)$i="  "}7' file
i1, 12, 15,
i2, 00, 01,
i3,   ,   ,
i4, 18, 21, 36
```

Note in line1 and 2, there are two trailing spaces if it does matter, you can add a `sub(/ *$/,"")`

Answer (score 1):

With Miller (http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc) using

```
mlr --nidx --fs ',' --repifs  unsparsify --fill-with "" inputFile
```

you have

```
i1, 12, 15,
i2, 00, 01,
i3,,,
i4, 18, 21, 36
```

Answer (score 1):

Another awk with `sort` if the order of the output lines doesn't matter

```
$ awk -F"," ' {print NF "," $0 } ' tane.txt  | sort -k1 -nr | awk -F, ' { if(NR==1) mx=NF;for(i=2;i<mx;i++) {$i=length($i)?$i:" "; printf "%s,", $i} print $i } '
i4, 18, 21, 36
i2, 00, 01,
i1, 12, 15,
i3, , ,

$
```

Input file

```
$ cat tane.txt
i1, 12, 15
i2, 00, 01
i3
i4, 18, 21, 36

$
```